# How to add ellipses and angled bracket to a exponential number in Latex?

Tags: latex

I am currently working on a Latex assignment, and was wondering how to code the exponent below with the ellipses (...) and the angled bracket.

[image: Assignment Instruction]

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{huge}
\[x^{\underbrace{1^{...^{1}}}_{n}}\]
\end{huge}
\end{document}
```

However, the result does not look exactly like the sketch. I hope it's helpful anyway.